# Adding contents in specific point of the text using vba

Tags: vba, selection, ms-word

I have a document template .docx which I have to edit adding strings in specific points. It looks like the following:

> **Test Mode:** Here some text has to be added and it can take more rows, it should be indented on each one.
>   **Items Involved:** Here some text has to be added ...
>   **Input and Simulation Parameters:** Here some text has to be added
>   ...

Until Kow I've been using the following code

```
Sub FillingParagraphs()
    Dim SubPara As Paragraph
    Dim SubLevel As String
    SubLevel = "3.1.1.1"
    'Filling each subparagraph
    For k = 1 To 3
        For Each SubPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
            j = j + 1
            If SubPara.Range.ListFormat.ListString = SubLevel Then
                Selection.Start = ActiveDocument.Content.ListString
            ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(j + 2).Range.Words(5) = "Text to be added" & Chr(10)
            MsgBox j
            End If
        Next
        'Update the string with the next subparagraph
            SubLevel = "3.1.1." & CStr(k + 1)
        j = 0
    Next
End Sub
```

Although it works, I need to specify the exact point where start writing counting the words and paragraphs:

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(j + 2).Range.Words(5)
```

and this way is not so smart, so I'd like to modofy my code in something like this:

```
Selection.Start = ActiveDocument.Content.END_SUBSTRING_1
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText (" Text to be added")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
Sub InsertText(findWhat As String, insertAfter As String)
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = findWhat
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = findWhat & " " & insertAfter
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
    End With
End Sub

Sub test()
    InsertText "some text to find", "some text to be added"
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good point to start because "I need to insert a different text on each findWhat". I mean, I should have something like, findWhat: first_Insert, findWhat: second_Insert and so on. Anyway this is very helpful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to change the procedure in the following, where I give a range to the function to search in:

```
Sub InsertText(findWhat As String, insertAfter As String, MyRange As Range)
    With ActiveDocument.MyRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = findWhat
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = findWhat & " " & insertAfter
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
    End With
End Sub
```

so in another part of the code I define a range and set it with default values, then reset my range according to my needs:

```
Level1 = "3.1.1.1"
Level2 = "3.1.1.2"
```

'Define MyRange with default values

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim StartRange As Integer
Dim EndRange As Integer
Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
```

'Redefine MyRange

```
For Each RngPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        i = i + 1
        If RngPara.Range.ListFormat.ListString = Level1 Then
        StartRange = i
        ElseIf RngPara.Range.ListFormat.ListString = Level2 Then
        EndRange = i
        End If

        MyRange.SetRange     Start:=MyRange.Start,End:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(3).Range.End
Next 
InsertText "Scope of test:", Scopo(j), MyRange
```

It does not work anyway! What is wrong with that?